# How to solve the Hot Key conflict issue of NetBeans (under Ubuntu)?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7.2

I installed NetBeans 7.2 under my Ubuntu 12.04. And to invoke javadoc, I press the HOT KEY Alt+F1 when mouse is on the word, but it will only trigger Ubuntu's Applications menu on the top-left corner of my desktop (Gnome). How to solve the conflict issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressing Ctrl-Space at the end of a class or variable name will also show JavaDoc in NetBeans.
Alternatively, you can change or disable the Gnome shortcut, or change the NetBeans shortcut.

Comment: In my Ubuntu, to press Ctrl-Space will invode the Chinese character input...So how to change the NetBeans shortcut or Ubuntu's shortcut? Thanks!

Comment: To change the NetBeans shortcut, go to the Keymap section of the NetBeans options.